# AST Diff Extractor for Java

Tags: java, diff, abstract-syntax-tree, patch

Assume I have two source codes like these ones:

prog1:

```
public class MathUtils4M0
{

    public  int getMaxAdjacentSum( int[] numbers )
    {
        if (numbers == null || numbers.length < 2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length * 1; i++) {
                int temp = numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1];
                if (temp > max) {
                    max = temp;
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
    }

}
```

prog2:

```
public class MathUtils4M92
{

    public  int getMaxAdjacentSum( int[] numbers )
    {
        if (numbers == null || numbers.length < 2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
                int temp = numbers[i] + numbers[1];
                if (temp > max) {
                    max = temp;
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
    }

}
```

which are different with each other in the line `int temp = numbers[i] + numbers[1];` compared to `int temp = numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1];`.

I can extract the AST of those codes thanks to antlr. For example the output is like this:

[image: AST comparision]

Which are exactly same to each other but the location specified by red color.

Antlr also gives a visiting mechanism which takes my visitor and visits the tree from root to the bottom (if helps).

The question:

Is there any API, library, or specific algorithm (implemented or not) to take the difference?

Like patches given from git or diff-match-patch. For example, in the above example, I want to know (get) that,

[image: before]

is replaced by:

[image: after]

or more accurate,

[image: diff]

as the difference.

### Update

Although my question is about the diff in ASTs, but the general solution of tree comparison (not a simple comparison, but with diff output) should work in this place.

Comment: See our SmartDifferencer tool that does this and reports the results as deltas.  http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I have found a way. By now I have found the right library (at least I think) but still I have a way to get use of that in my own code.

The tool is:

http://www.labri.fr/perso/falleri/perso/tools/gumtree/

with a github page of:

https://github.com/GumTreeDiff/gumtree

that gives me the awesome output of:

[image: ast diff]